# Invalid escape sequence in literal

Tags: ios, swift

Suppose to be a easy one

I get a compiler error for this:

```
var str:String = "117\/7024"
```

I gauss i have a problem with either / but i cant find an answer how to correct this String

Comment: Apple's Swft book explains in detail what characters you can and can't put into a String literal.

Comment: Your code was not rendered correctly in the initial version of the question . Is this what you actually meant?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you are trying to re-define `str` which you might have defined before yourself. I would not recommend this type of variable name, even if it is legal.

Also, you need to leave a space after the `=`.

EDIT: Your original question quoted the string as `"117/7024"`, which does not give this error. I suppose you meant to write `"117\7024"`.

To escape a backslash, use `"117\\7024"`.
To actually get the unicode character "瀤", use `"177\u{7024}"`.

Comment: Yes, I but based on the previous version of the question I assumed the OP defined it himself before.