# string replace occurence generates error for \ character

Tags: swift, string

and I want to replace `\/` and `\` character with `/`. Hence I used string's `replacingOccurrences` function, but it generates error as *"Invalid escape sequence in literal"*. Below is my string, and replacingOccurrence function. Also I have attached screenshot for the same.kindly help

[image: error screenshot]

```
var str = "http:\/\/colesi.com\/exapp\/upload.png"
let ans = str.replacingOccurrences(of: "\/", with: "/")
let ansq = str.replacingOccurrences(of: "\", with: "")
```

Comment: further more you can also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31287879/invalid-escape-sequence-in-literal

Answer (score 3):

You need to understand what `\` is used for, it is for escaping special characters, like `"` inside a string. You cannot write `let str = " " "` but you need to write `let str = " \" "`. Since `\` is treated specially you need to escape it when trying to write it literally: `let str = " \\ "` instead of `let str = " \ "` . `/` itself is not "escapable", `\/` does not mean anything and is invalid.

That means in your particular case all three shown lines are invalid. Either it should be

```
var str = "http:\\/\\/colesi.com\\/exapp\\/upload.png"
```

or

```
var str = "http://colesi.com/exapp/upload.png"
```

to start with. In the second case you dont need to do anything.

In the first case you need to do

```
let ans = str.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\", with: "")
```

I am gussing here: I think you copied that url from *somewhere* where it has been escaped in *some* way and are trying to counteract that, chances are you do not need to do that at all.